# Alert when someone access my machine share?

Tags: windows-7

I'm wondering if there's a application that alerts me if someone (in my network) access a shared folder?

I can see the sessions opened in Computer Management but i want to know if someone's accessing/sneeking in my shared folders.

What would make me smile is a taskbar popup alert when someone accesses my shares.

Thank U All..

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with WMI scripting - set up a [temporary event consumer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#event_consumers) which watches for creation of [Win32_ServerConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394416.aspx) instances.

The WQL would look something like:

```
select * from __InstanceCreationEvent where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_ServerConnection'
```